# Django- Redirect to same view without reloading

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a view (views.loaditems) which runs some algorithm and passes items to a template(product.html) where the items are loaded, and with each item, I have a "add_to_shortlist" link. On clicking this link, the item is added in the user's shortlist (for which I have a function). I want that on click, the page is not reloaded and has its items, but simply add that item to the user's shortlist. Also, where should I define this shortlist function?

I'm new to Django, and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Update: Here's my code:

views.py

```
def loaditems(request):
    #some code
    ourdeals = SDeals.objects.filter(**{agestring3:0})
    sorteddeals = ourdeals.order_by('-total_score')
    user = request.user     
    context = {'deals': sorteddeals, 'sl_products':sl_products, 'user':user,}
    template='index.html'
    return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def usersl(request, id, id2):
    userslt = User_Shortlist.objects.filter(id__iexact=id)
    products = SDeals.objects.filter(id__iexact=id2)
    product = products[0]
    if userslt:
        userslt[0].sdeals.add(product)
    sl = userslt[0].sdeals.all()
    return render_to_response('slnew.html', {'sl':sl}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in my index.html I have:

```
<div class="slist"><a href="/usersl/{{user.id}}/{{ deal.id }}"></a></div>
```

which in urls.py takes me to views.usersl:

```
url(r'^usersl/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<id2>\d+)/$', views.usersl),
```

I don't want to go to slnew.html, instead be on index.html without reloading it, and on click 'slist', just run the function to add to shortlist.

Comment: Maybe if you post some code, we will might be able to help you. Include the parts of the urls.py, your functions on your views.py and some of your html.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want to go to `slnew.html`, why are you specifying that (instead of `index.html`) in the `render_to_response` of `usersl`(btw, it is missing the `return` statement). If you don't want to reload the whole `index.html` you should use AJAX.

Comment: added the return statement.
I cant use index.html in my usersl render_to_response since it takes me to a fresh index.html, not the one in the previous state. The slnew.html is just a makeshift template I give, to check if my function is working. Is there a Django way to do it without using ajax?

Comment: By definition (of AJAX) you can't do it with just Django. I guess you will need to read a bit about [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (not a language, it is more a technology or a technique in which you manipulate the html with javascript but make petitions to a server). Good news is that it shouldn't be very complicated.

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't understand your problem. Why do you want to go to the previous state?

Comment: I guess there is but can you more elaborate what you need? Maybe you give us a sample output rather than explaining it.

Comment: an example would be a travel search engine (like kayak.com), where you put in your search criteria and items are loaded on a page according to your search. Now, if you have an add to shortlist button besides each item, and you click on it, that item gets added on the 'shortlist' feature on that very page. This shortlist section, which is initially empty when the page is loaded, gets filled up as the user adds different items to the shortlist.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make changes on the server and in a page without navigating with the browser you need to look at JavaScript solutions. Read up about Ajax. In essence you need to use some JavaScript to send the update to the server, and to change the HTML.

JQuery is one popular library that will help you to do this. A more sophisticated example is AngularJS. On the Django side you'll write some views that handle these small update tasks used in the page. Libraries like Django REST framework or Django Slumber will help you with that.